# How do I disable Command+Enter sending e-mail in Outlook 2011 for Mac?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2011

I accidentally send e-mails about twice a week because of Outlook's keyboard shortcut for <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> sending a message. How do I disable this keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard shortcuts -> Application Shortcuts. Now add Outlook/Entourage to the list and make sure that "Menu title" states "Send". After that choose whatever cryptic shortcut you are sure you will never accidentally hit.

Note that you have to quit Outlook, make the change in System Preferences and relaunch Outlook 2011 for the change to take effect.

Comment: Finally! Now please tell me how to get those prematurely sent messages back.

Comment: It wasn't immediately obvious how to add "Outlook" - I had to go to the bottom to find "other", then select "Microsoft Office" and only then was Outlook available as a choice. (But thanks for this helpful answer!)

Comment: If you get here looking for how to do this same thing in Lync, the answer is basically the same.  The app is Microsoft Lync and the Menu Title is "Start Lync Call"

Comment: thank you! Why on earth microsoft would even set a hotkey for that by default is beyond me. Typing fast and pasting something I accidently send a mail to 8 of my colleagues that was half written.

Comment: that's the correct answer!

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer not to have *any* keyboard shortcut assigned to the "Send" command (as I do) I suggest using a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) character (set via the below Terminal command). This will effectively disable the keyboard shortcut completely:

```
defaults write com.microsoft.Outlook NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Send" "\U200B"
```

Be sure Outlook is not running when you issue this command, or the preference may not be saved.

Comment: you saved my day!